# Calculate top 20% and bottom 20% using Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm kind of new in Tableau and I've been blocked since a few days with this issue. I will try to explain as best as I can. *I can only use Tableau Desktop, not Prep.*
I'm trying to recreate the line graph attached: a comparison by month of the 20% best scores, the general average score, and the 20% worst scores.
Things I tried:

1. Because each tile needs to have the same number of rows and that some scores can be duplicated, I used INDEX() to number the rows.

```
INDEX()
```

2. With the Index(), I created a calculated field for the tiles from 1 to 5.

```
IF [index]<=WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.2 
    then 1
ELSEIF WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.2<[index] 
    and [index]<=WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.4 
    then 2
ELSEIF WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.4<[index] 
    and [index]<=WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.6
    then 3
ELSEIF WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.6<[index] 
    and [index]<=WINDOW_COUNT(MIN(ZN([Score])))*0.8
    then 4
else 5
END
```

This is as far as I could get.

How I wish I could continue:

1. create calculated field 'Best 20%':
   if tile = 1 then avg(score) end
2. create calculated field 'Worst 20%':
   if tile = 5 then avg(score) end

Other precisions:

1. There will be a date granularity filter to change from month to week.
2. There will also be a filter by age group.

In SQL, I would use something similar to this:

```
WITH buckets AS (
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('month',datetime::DATE) AS date
    , ntile(5) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY ZEROIFNULL(score)) AS global_buckets
FROM scores
ORDER BY 1
)
, top_bottom AS (
SELECT 
    DISTINCT date
    , avg(CASE WHEN global_buckets = 1 THEN avg(score) END) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS best_20
    , avg(CASE WHEN global_buckets_by_country = 5 THEN avg(score) END) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS worst_20
FROM buckets
ORDER BY 1)
SELECT *
FROM top_bottom
```

How could I move forward with this?[how my final graph should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCHu9.png)